# Stop IMG tag overflowing

Tags: html, css, adobe, overflow

How do I stop a single div from overflowing vertically, after using position absolute. I have an img tag that links to an SVG in a folder.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some code to get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `overflow: hidden;` or `z-index: -1;` for the image. And can you please share youre Code if you need something else